# Aggregate availability on Calendars between work and personal

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, office365, calendar, icloud

My problem is as follows,

"Even more important now when we are between home and the office… is the management of our calendars and availability.
 
Background information,
I have my main work (a***@m**.com ) calendar “Calendar” that all my meeting’s sit in, and controls my availability for “My Organization” to be able to view my busy/ free hours, when scheduling meetings.
I also have a 2x sub-calendars under this main calendar “Calendar”, called “Personal” and “Relationship” however because they are sub-calendars, they don’t merge my availability so that “My Organization” is able to view my busy/ free hours.
 
I like having these 3x different calendars, because I can show/hide them as I need… but of course having these sub-calendars means that I might have an appointment in “Personal” but when “My Organization” views my availability for scheduling meetings, they believe I’m free.
Therefore duplicating my meetings in my “Personal” and main “Calendar” for the same time.
 
Article for better explanation,
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange/aggregate-availability-from-multiple-calendars/m-p/137286
 
I was hoping someone would know of a better solution for this, besides manually creating blank meetings in the main “Calendar” account to block out meetings that are scheduled in my “Personal” and “Relationship” sub-calendars.
 
Side note,
The “Relationship” calendar is a calendar that’s shared between myself and my partner, so that if there’s a family dinner, after works drinks, or appointment that involves us both, it’s a nice way of either one of us having the option see the availability of each other.. and then of course add in a new appointment if need be  or reschedule it- if we are already doing something on that day.

Thanks in advance for any help :)"

Answer (score 0):

My Outlook calendar is my aggregated calendar, but I use Categories to visually distinguish between the different kinds of appt's (Work, Personal, Sports, etc.).  This way my co-workers can tell if I'm out for a personal reason, and I can show/hide the Categories as needed.

However, as is common, some of these appt's might be shared with family or friends, and I've found Google calendars to be great for this.  iCloud calendars are OK too, but there's a tool called gSyncIt, available from https://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/, that helps with this.  Not associated with them, just happy.

Basically, this integrates to Outlook and syncs appt's of certain Categories with my Google calendar(s).  So, at work, I can see everything, and at home we can share calendars and not have to duplicate any entries.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Outlook desktop client does not support the aggregate availability on Calendars you mentioned. We can only overload sub calendars on primary calendar to make ourselves easy to tell in which time you are busy or free.

Answer (score 0):

Digging the jimtut solution, https://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/, I was able to sync a Google Calendar to Outlook 365 calendar in a category I named "AvailabilityNAME" and obfuscate all sensitive infos, keeping people from booking me when I'm unavailable working on some other things in life. Thank you so much jimtut :)
I had to search for more than 2 hours for this solution, and I believe this is the only reasonable way to do it.
If you were to want to sync more than one Google Calendar to one Outlook Calendar, and not just overlay like some suggest, you should just create one category in the Outlook calendar per Google calendar you want to sync, to avoid merging/updating conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this, for a while, via a web calendar sync platform called [www.syncgene.com](http://www.syncgene.com)

It got the job done. Unfortunately, my company e-mail no longer allows external apps to connect to it, and I'm back to square one.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1143440)